# Custom Getter & Setter iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, getter-setter

I want to override the getter and setter in my ObjC class using ARC.

.h File

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) Season *season;
```

.m File

```
@synthesize season;


- (void)setSeason:(Season *)s {
    self.season = s; 

    // do some more stuff
}

- (Season *)season {
    return self.season;
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Note that this pattern leads to madness;  in particular, it means that `setSeason:` must always be an atomic, integral, operation on your data model.  If your code were to evolve such that there was another property whose value was dependent on `season`, then you are left with an ordering dependency ("I must set 'other' before I call `setSeason:` because `setSeason:` has business logic that depends on 'other').  Best to keep setter/getter stupid simple and keep the business logic separate.

Comment: Well in my case, I'll just update the view with new data from the `season`...

Comment: But if you keep the setter/getter stupid simple and keep the business logic separate you've just moved the problem.  Now you'd have to remember that every time you call `setSeason:` you also have to call `someBusinessLogicBasedOnSeason:` and you still have to wonder if you need to do all of that before or after you set other.

Comment: A good pattern is using setter to invalidate data, e.g. there are two setters `setSeason:`, `setYear:` and they both do `_seasonalDataNeedsUpdate = YES;`. Real update happens later, if still necessary (e.g. if user did not cancel). This takes care of order and ensures we do not pull the same information several times.

Comment: Oh my god ilya, thank you so much! I was literally pulling my hair wondering why the _ notation sometimes work and sometimes doesn't.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Yep, those are infinite recursive loops. That's because

```
self.season = s;
```

is translated by the compiler into

```
[self setSeason:s];
```

and

```
return self.season;
```

is translated into

```
return [self season];
```

Get rid of the *dot-accessor* `self.` and your code will be correct.

This syntax, however, can be confusing given that your property `season` and your variable `season` share the same name (although Xcode will somewhat lessen the confusion by coloring those entities differently). It is possible to explicitly change your variable name by writing

```
@synthesize season = _season;
```

or, better yet, omit the `@synthesize` directive altogether. The modern Objective-C compiler will automatically synthesize the accessor methods and the instance variable for you.

Comment: I want to meet the genius who made `self.season = s` be translated to `[self setSeason:s]`

Comment: @RenatoLochetti that's just how dot notation works.  What would you rather the method be called?

Comment: It should be better if it just access the attribute. Two different things: access the attribute and call setter method.

Comment: In Xcode 5, if you provide both custom getter and setter, system no longer synthesizes the member variable. You must use @synthesize to do this. It is no longer optional as you have suggested.

Answer (score 16):

If you are going to implement your own getter and setter, you'll need to maintain an internal variable:

```
@synthesize season = _season;

- (void)setSeason:(Season *)s {
    // set _season
    //Note, if you want to retain (as opposed to assign or copy), it should look someting like this
    //[_season release];
    //_season = [s retain];
}

- (Season *)season {
    // return _season
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks that did the job. Would you recommend using `_season` instead of `self.season` all the time then?

Comment: The _ (underscore) is a matter of preference, but makes it clear that it's an internal variable.

Comment: Well the internal variable `season` is always there. The only thing `season = _season` does is renaming this variable. This is however not necessary. @jlehr explained how this works.

Comment: awesome you saved me 2 days of tweaking my code. especially this bit         //Note, if you want to retain (as opposed to assign or copy), it should look someting like this
    //[_season release];
    //_season = [s retain];

Comment: Note that the internal variable actually defaults to `_season`, `@synthesize season = _season` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

The thing you’re missing is that the Objective-C compiler basically turns the `self.foo = bar` syntax into `[self setFoo:bar]`, and `self.foo` into `[self foo]`. Your methods, as currently implemented, are calling themselves. As Jeremy suggests, you need to implement them such that the setter actually assigns the value it’s called with to an instance variable on your class and the getter returns the value of that instance variable.