# Access to a variable from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, setter

I'm working on a project in objective C where i have to modificate some variables which are in a view controller from uiviews.

So i've tried somethings like this :

ViewController.h :

```
@property (nonatomic) bool Contact;
```

One of the UIViews :

```
ViewController * View;
View.Contact = YES;
```

I've also tried to make a setter method like this in the ViewController :

```
-(void) SetterContact:(bool)boolean;
```

And so to modificate from a UIView like this :

```
[View SetterContact:YES];
```

But it's looking working.
I've read that i have to init the object in which is containt the variable, but in memory management it's not really good to make some initializations from object who are already actives no ?
So if View is already init, i'm not going to call the init method from another UIView no ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want bool variable to be accessible from other viewController.Then simply wirte it as :-

```
@property BOOL Contact;
```

and make an object of ViewController in which you have declared contact variable as BOOL and access this variable using like this:-

```
OtherViewController *otherViewController=[[OtherViewController alloc] init];
otherViewController.Contact=YES;
```

As it is a instance variable it has to be accessed using class object.

Comment: Returns an error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil' but i dont' have any NSarray in those two view controllers...

Comment: paste you viewController's code on pastebin so that I can see it deeply what you have done in your code

Comment: I just write : if (!World)
        {
            World = [[World_1_ViewController alloc] init];            
        }
        World.Contact = YES;          Furthermore, that code looks like working in another viewcontroller -_-'

Comment: Ok, you need to check in currentViewController in which error displaying.If on other ViewController is working there is no issue in declaring bool varible.

Comment: I have checked, and all is the same as in my other view controller which is working. Really don't know how to fix it...

Comment: strange error.Bool variable giving NSArray error?Need to find out deeply.Run app in zombie profile.And check where it quits

Comment: No, it's only those lines which are making fail : if (!World)
        {
            World = [[World_1_ViewController alloc] init];
        }   And if i don't put them, world object is not init, and  World.Contact = YES; couldn't work :/

Comment: you mean  if (!World) { World = [[World_1_ViewController alloc] init]; } line causing error

Comment: use this one :--  World_1_ViewController *world=[[World_1_ViewController alloc] init];  world.Contact=YES;

Comment: Same error when i try World_1_ViewController *world=[[World_1_ViewController alloc] init]; world.Contact=YES; Really strange...

Comment: I really don't know how to fix this sort of error, because it's work in another view controller with other parameters defines like here.

Comment: I've done the methode which is here... : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: you can try initwithnibname I am not sure but may be it help you.

Comment: I don't have nib, so it didn't change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Respect naming conventions
   `@property (nonatomic,retain) UIViewController *myController;`

don't forget to synthesize
`@synthesize myController = _myController;`

2. If you want to implement your own setter do this: respect the naming convention
   `-(void)setMyController:(UIViewController*)controller;`
3. or if by any bizarre reason you can't respect naming convention you can point the property to the method you want
   `@property (nonatomic,retain,setter=myBizarreSetterMethod:) UIViewController *myController;`

this can help you out as well [question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730816/custom-getter-setter-ios-5)

Answer (score 0):

use `@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isContact) BOOL contact;` in your .h file.

Comment: in my project i use NSSString instead @"YES"

Comment: so @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString isContact;

Comment: ViewController *view = [ViewController alloc] init];
view.isContact = @"YES";

Comment: you dont need to create your own get/setter and no need to init the NSString isContact nor synthesize.

Comment: How could i do a setter ? Easily

Comment: no need to create a setter just use 
view.isContact = @"YES";

Comment: Nop, sorry. But i've fixed it whith another variable.