# Calling setter method of a property on its instance varaible

Tags: ios

- I have 3 properties `id_1`, `id_2`, `id_3`
- `id_2` and `id_3` are derived from `id_1`
- `id_1` can have public getter/setter
- `id_2` and `id_3` only have `readonly` access.

So I need to override the setter for `id_1` to set `id_2` and `id_3` for valid `id_1`

- `id_1` could come from `NSUserDefaults` which means in `init`, I need to set `id_2` and `id_3`
- So, I wanted to call setter of `id_1` from `init` as if I was calling from outside of the class using `ivar` `_id_1`
- That would give me a single implementation to set all the ids both during `init` phase or if called externally

My question is on following two lines that I have in my code as I am calling the **setter** for `id_1` with argument as `ivar _id_1`

```
        _id_1 = id_from_ns_user_defaults
        [self setid_1:_id_1];
```

In few other SO articles I saw concerns around recursive loops

[Custom Getter & Setter iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730816/custom-getter-setter-ios-5)

.h file

```
@interface UserCredentials : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *id_1;
@property (readonly) NSString *id_2;
@property (readonly) NSString *id_3;

@end
```

.m file

```
@interface UserCredentials ()

@property (readwrite) NSString *id_2;
@property (readwrite) NSString *id_3;

@end

@implementation UserCredentials

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

         /* Is this valid in Objective-C */

        _id_1 = id_from_ns_user_defaults
        [self setid_1:_id_1];
    }
    return  self;
}


- (void)setid_1:(NSString *)id
{
   if (id && ![id isEqualToString:@""]) {
          _id_1 = id;
          _id_2 = convert2(_id_1);
          _id_3 = convert3(_id_1);
   }

}

@end
```

Comment: If `id_2` and `id_3` are derived from `id_1`, why should you store their values at all? Why not just implement getters that compute the value when needed?

Comment: I think I have an expensive computation and other uses....but was just wanted to understand if its ok to do what I posted

Comment: @michaels..thanks for pointing that out....I was not thinking in that direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your highlighted concern is around creating an assignment cycle. Because you are assigning to the ivar itself, you will not be creating a cycle. Remember that manipulating the ivar will not cause your getter/setter to be called -- it's just a pointer like any other pointer.

---

Setting an ivar to itself is not an issue unless you have done something in your setter implementation to make it an issue. In non-ARC systems, you could easily create a bad access error by implementing your setter with the wrong order:

```
- (void)setVal:(NSObject *)val {
  [_val release];
  _val = [val retain];
}
```

This is countered by using `autorelease` instead (or assigning to a temporary variable and releasing after the `retain`).

Most of the time, though, your setter won't be doing anything destructive when passed a new (or same) value. Your implementation does not do this.